# How can I batch rename multiple images with their path names and reordered sequences in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, rename, batch-processing, mv

My pictures are kept in the folder with the picture-date for folder name, for example the original path and file names:

```
.../Pics/2016_11_13/wedding/DSC0215.jpg
.../Pics/2016_11_13/afterparty/DSC0234.jpg
.../Pics/2016_11_13/afterparty/DSC0322.jpg
```

How do I rename the pictures into the format below, with continuous sequences and 4-digit padding?

```
.../Pics/2016_11_13_wedding.0001.jpg
.../Pics/2016_11_13_afterparty.0002.jpg
.../Pics/2016_11_13_afterparty.0003.jpg
```

I'm using Bash 4.1, so only mv command is available. Here is what I have now but it's not working

```
#!/bin/bash

p=0
for i in *.jpg;
do
  mv "$i" "$dirname.%03d$p.JPG"
  ((p++))
done

exit 0
```

Comment: and there are gaps in the original sequence cuz I deleted some of the pics, but the final image sequence has to be continuous.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: search here for `[linux] find xargs mv printf`. You should find many examples that will help you solve your problem. You need to use `%04d` inside of a program that knows how to evaluate that place-holder (`printf`). and you need to take the output of a command and substitute it into your real command (cmd-substition) with `$(printf ....)`. Good luck.

Comment: Why is this tagged Linux if you're using Git Bash?

Comment: @muru cuz I'm sending the pictures to a shop to get a wedding album made, they're running Red Hat

Comment: So which is it? Red Hat or Git bash? Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: this question is confusing: if you run on redhat you'll run on normal bash. If you run on git bash that means you run this on windows. But also you say that "only mv command is available" which is not true, in git bash `find`, `grep` and even `awk` are available. Please clarify these open questions

Comment: egh, just assume I'm using Bash 4.1

Comment: Well, your for loop isn't going to work as you need to be moving to each directory.  As you want to move them all to the top directory of 'Pics' (possibly bad idea if it goes awry), you should feed a while loop with find and perform mv's inside that.  As advised above, you will need to incorporate printf into the solution to get the padding.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have something like .../Pics/2016_11_13/wedding/XXXXXX.jpg; then go in directory .../Pics/2016_11_13; from there, you should have a bunch of subdirectories like wedding, afterparty, and so on. Launch this script (disclaimer: I didn't test it):

```
#!/bin/sh
for subdir in *; do                # scan directory
  [ ! -d "$subdir" ] && continue;  # skip non-directory
  prognum=0;                       # progressive number
  for file in $(ls "$dir"); do     # scan subdirectory
    (( prognum=$prognum+1 ))          # increment progressive
    newname=$(printf %4.4d $prognum)  # format it
    newname="$subdir.$newname.jpg"    # compose the new name
    if [ -f "$newname" ]; then        # check to not overwrite anything
      echo "error: $newname already exist."
      exit
    fi

    # do the job, move or copy
    cp "$subdir/$file" "$newname"

  done
done
```

Please note that I skipped the "date" (2016_11_13) part - I am not sure about it. If you have a single date, then it is easy to add these digits in *# compose the new name*. If you have several dates, then you can add a nested `for` for scanning the "date" directories. One more reason I skipped this, is to let you develop something by yourself, something you can be proud of...

Answer (score 1):

Using only `mv` and bash builtins:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
cd Pics
p=1
# recursive glob for .jpg files
for i in **/*.jpg
do
    # (date)/(event)/(filename).jpg
    if [[ $i =~ (.*)/(.*)/(.*).jpg ]]
    then
        newname=$(printf "%s_%s.%04d.jpg" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}" "$p")
        echo mv "$i" "$newname"
        ((p++))
    fi
done
```

`globstar` is a bash 4.0 feature, and regex matching is available even in OSX's anitque bash.